# Trying to add a vertical div and other content get pushed down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add in verticle div handler between other divs. For whatever reason, the other divs get pushed down. I don't know why.

https://jsfiddle.net/paralaxwombat/dcog2pem/2/

You can take a look at the jsfiddle above and the code below.

Edit. What I need is to have all of the divs be aligned with one another with the handler div in between.

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;


}

.entire-col{
   display:table;
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
   table-layout:relative;
   float: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I justed edited the main post. What I need is to have all of the divs be aligned with one another with the handler div in between.

Comment: dou you want them vertically aligned or horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using flexbox for this instead of imitating a table. Fixed it here with flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/gm2c5v8u/

```css
.entire-col {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    float: inherit;
}

.col-container {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. That solves my problem. Why is the flex box better?

Comment: Great! Can you mark it as the correct answer? Flexbox is a more modern method, made for these kind of layouts. Learning it will save you a lot of time in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  
  
}

.entire-col{
  display: flex;
flex-flow: row warp;
   display:table;
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
   table-layout:relative;
   float: inherit;
}


.col-container {
  flex-basis: 20%
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.col{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

.handler{
  flex-basis: 20%
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  
}

.selection{
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="entire-col">
  
  <div class="col-container" id="window0">
    <div class="col" style="background:lightgrey">
      <div class="selection">
        <select class="codeSelectChooser">
          <option id='Option A'>Option A</option>
          <option id='Option B'>Option B</option>
          <option id='Option C'>Option C</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
      <h1> Area 1</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  
  <div class="handler">
    Hallo
  </div>

  
  
  <div class="col-container" id="window1">
    <div class="col" style="background:red">
      <div class="selection">
        <select class="codeSelectChooser">
          <option id='Option A'>Option A</option>
          <option id='Option B'>Option B</option>
          <option id='Option C'>Option C</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
      <h1> Area 2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="handler">
    
  </div>


  
  <div class="col-container" id="window1">
    <div class="col" style="background:lightgreen">
      <div class="selection">
        <select class="codeSelectChooser">
          <option id='Option A'>Option A</option>
          <option id='Option B'>Option B</option>
          <option id='Option C'>Option C</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
      <h1> Area 3</h1>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
      <div class="handler">
    
  </div>


  
  
  <div class="col-container" id="window1">
    <div class="col" style="background:lightblue">
      <div class="selection">
        <select class="codeSelectChooser">
          <option id='Option A'>Option A</option>
          <option id='Option B'>Option B</option>
          <option id='Option C'>Option C</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
      <h1> Area 4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
    



  
</body>
</html>
```

As the previous answer suggests you should probably use flexbox to align your items.

remove all the `display: table`-like-stuff and rely on flexbox:

https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/